# PHP copy performance with larger video files

Tags: php, video, copy, copy-paste

I'm looking in to performing a function in my app where I copy or move video files form one folder to another via an HTML page.

This function is done once a video has been viewed by an administrator and is suitable for public view and moved to a different folder from it's original. The videos are already stored on the server.

I'm wondering if the PHP copy function is suitable with the following requirements:

1. For large files (for arguments sake 30Mb)
2. When the copy function is performed is this instantaneous or will it
   take a certain time to execute depending on server configuration etc
3. Once the function is called is it dependent on internet connection
   speed (could we do this on a mobile over 3G for example).
4. Is moving quicker and more efficient than duplicating

I apologize for multiple sections to my question, any advice on this would be very helpful

Thanks,

P

Comment: no. copy literally duplicates the bytes. If you copy a 10gig file, it'll take however long it takes to shove 10gigs around on your storage system. Moving **SHOULD** be quicker, but only if it's within the same file system. moving to a different filesystem is just a copy+delete.

Comment: In general I would recommend neither. You probably should have a database or so in the background to manage access to that file. If the admin has reviewed the video those rights are changed to "publicly available". No need to copy or move anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Moving is always much faster than copying data- as the OS only needs
  to adjust the file's location, not recreate it. I would recommend
  moving the file and you should see a nearly instant response from the
  move command.
- The connection speed does not impact the performance of the PHP, as the PHP is run server-side. The PHP will respond at the same speed regardless of the user's connection.
- The best solution would be to leave the files in an upload folder and instead save an "access" column in the database that determines if this file should be served publicly or not. This creates a much more flexible system.

Comment: Thanks Mikel good advice. The 'original videos' are secure and only accessed by SSL, I want to move to a directory with no SSL. I'll try some performance tests and see how I get on. I might try the DB option though as this might save many potential problems.

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions or run into any problems!